# Error deploying CF on virtualbox using Bosh

Tags: cf-bosh

I am using mac OS and trying to deploy CF on virtualbox using BOSH.

BOSH Director installed has the following details

```
$ bosh -e vbox env
Using environment '192.168.50.6' as user 'admin'

Name      bosh-lite  
UUID      bbdcc68d-5390-4d08-bd80-900bf3aa3551  
Version   268.2.0 (00000000)  
CPI       warden_cpi  
Features  compiled_package_cache: disabled  
          config_server: enabled  
          local_dns: enabled  
          power_dns: disabled  
          snapshots: disabled  
User      admin
```

Bosh CLI version is

```
version 5.4.0-891ff634-2018-11-14T00:21:14Z
```

To deploy CF, I run the following script

```
bosh -e 192.168.50.6 -d cf deploy \
  cf-deployment.yml \
  -o operations/bosh-lite.yml \
  -v system_domain=bosh-lite.com
```

I get the following error:

```
Task 33 | 15:26:34 | Updating instance diego-api: diego-api/95e076b7-0fc4-43e0-9db6-afbd8b79d76d (0) (canary) (00:20:19)
                   L Error: 'diego-api/95e076b7-0fc4-43e0-9db6-afbd8b79d76d (0)' is not running after update. Review logs for failed jobs: bbs, silk-controller, locket
Task 33 | 15:46:53 | Error: 'diego-api/95e076b7-0fc4-43e0-9db6-afbd8b79d76d (0)' is not running after update. Review logs for failed jobs: bbs, silk-controller, locket

Task 33 Started  Fri Nov 16 15:24:57 UTC 2018
Task 33 Finished Fri Nov 16 15:46:53 UTC 2018
Task 33 Duration 00:21:56
Task 33 error

Updating deployment:
  Expected task '33' to succeed but state is 'error'

Exit code 1
```

cf-deployment file and ops file (from iaas/bosh-lite/cloud-config.yml) folder) that I use are from

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment
```

I also uploaded ubuntu-xenial stemcell that the cf-deployment file uses

There is a similar issue reported here

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/issues/1047
```

but I couldn't really gather the solution.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and move on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found this [github issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/issues/648)

To fix it I executed:

`bosh update-runtime-config bosh-deployment/runtime-configs/dns.yml --name dns`

I hope this fixes your problem as well ;)

Comment: Is there a way to ssh in to the VM created on virtualbox by bosh and check the logs ? I tried to use admin as username and admin_password in creds.yml but that didn't work.

Comment: You can use a jumpbox. You have to create your environment with jumpbox user enabled ` -o ~/workspace/bosh-deployment/jumpbox-user.yml` [bosh-lite on Virtualbox](https://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite/) and then follow the [Enabling SSH Access](https://bosh.io/docs/jumpbox/) guide.

Than check the [Using Logs](https://bosh.io/docs/job-logs/) and [bosh cli log command](https://bosh.io/docs/sysadmin-commands/#logs)

Comment: so once i have deployed cf on a virtualbox using bosh, how do i push an app in cf? Are there any special instructions around that somewhere ? I was also not able to enable ssh access. I didn't like the key that i interpolated from creds.yml and gave a warning "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! "

Comment: check your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, delete the key from the bosh vm and try to enable ssh access once again.
There are many tutorials in the web on how to deploy an app  you will find one that will work for you ;)

Comment: what do you mean when you say delete the key from bosh vm? I didn't quite follow that.

Comment: delete the line containing the bosh vm from the ssh known_host file. On GNU/Linux the file is ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: Do I need to ssh in to BOSH vm to suspend or turn on vagrant ? I used https://bosh.io/docs/quick-start/ to install BOSH and wondering if it uses vagrant under the covers

Comment: Every time my mac laptop goes in sleep mode, all vms go unresponsive. someone suggested to use vagrant suspend to halt all the VMs before putting the laptop in sleep mode. However, with latest bosh deployment, I don't see it using vagrant. So not sure how to resolve this issue. It is a never ending process. Issues keep coming one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

I found the above answer works if you have UAA and Credhub deployed. If you are using vars-store, I found the following issue to be relevant:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/issues/617

The command from above changes slightly:

`bosh -e vbox update-runtime-config <(bosh int bosh-deployment/runtime-configs/dns.yml --vars-store deployment-vars.yml) --name dns`

I think the gist is that you are feeding replacement variables found in dns.yml with the value found in deployment-vars.yml and the result is fed into update-runtime-config.